# Mongoose findOneAndUpdate() creates a new object

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying via PUT request to backend to update an existing document by using findOneAndUpdate().
the result of my code is that a replica of the original document is created rather updating the exisiting one and first record on page is removed.

```js
app.put('/update', async (req, res) => {
    const { fullname, phone, country, img, title, id } = req.body

    const countryData = getCountryCodeByName(country)

    await Contact.findOneAndUpdate(id, {
        fullname,
        title,
        phone,
        country,
        img,
        countryCode: countryData[0].dial_code
    }, { upsert: true, new: true })
        .then((data) => console.log(data))
    // console.log(id, resp._id)
    return res.status(200).json({
        message: 'Updated successfuly, Refreshing...',
        error: 0
    })
})
```

This is from frontend

```js
const updateUser = async () => {
        await axios.put('/update', {
            fullname,
            phone,
            country,
            img,
            title,
            id
        })
            .then((dataFetched) => {
                updateIsLoading(false)
                const { status, data } = dataFetched
                updateData({ data, status })
                window.location.href = '/'
            })
            .catch(err => {
                updateIsLoading(false)
                const { data, status } = err.response
                updateData({ data, status })
            })
    }
```

For example if I edit either the blue or green record, always the red one will be removed and changed to the edited document, and a new document will be created by that action.

[image: Example for code behaviour]

Comment: upsert set to true creates a new document if none is found

Comment: @jamomani I did remove and and still it keeps the old document and create a new one with a new ObjectID

Comment: To me it looks you are not passing the parameters correctly, for example the first param should be a document, is it a document? Upsert should be a boolean but instead you are passing it inside an object. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/. I might be wrong but I would check the parameters.

Comment: I did remove the upsert value and followed the docs. I added a screenshot with explanation for what is happening when I update a document

Answer (score 2):

I think you shoud use {} in find

```
  app.put('/update', async (req, res) => {
        const { fullname, phone, country, img, title, id } = req.body
    
        const countryData = getCountryCodeByName(country)
    
        await Contact.findOneAndUpdate({id}, {
            fullname,
            title,
            phone,
            country,
            img,
            countryCode: countryData[0].dial_code
        }, { upsert: true, new: true })
            .then((data) => console.log(data))
        // console.log(id, resp._id)
        return res.status(200).json({
            message: 'Updated successfuly, Refreshing...',
            error: 0
        })
    })
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer javad moulaei! I added to the original question and explanation at the bottom, how the code is behaving, which is kind of weird. I did remove upsert from the query and added {} for the id and it is still happening.

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out.
I wanted to find a document by an id and used findOneAndUpdate rather than findByIdAndUpdate.

This code now works just fine.

```js
app.put('/update', async (req, res) => {
    const { fullname, phone, country, img, title, id } = req.body

    const countryData = getCountryCodeByName(country)

    await Contact.findByIdAndUpdate(id, {
        fullname,
        phone,
        country,
        img,
        title,
        countryCode: countryData[0].dial_code
    }, { new: true })
        .then((data) => console.log(data))
        .catch((err) => console.log(err))

    return res.status(200).json({
        message: 'Updated successfuly, Refreshing...',
        error: 0
    })
})
```